# fedora 36 encrypted drive password prompt

Tags: fedora, firefox, luks

when i open firefox I get prompted for a password.
I have tried looking it up and cant find any answers or similar problems.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: May you clarify the exact way that you're using Fedora? Is it, for example, somebody else's computer? A live USB? A fresh install?

Comment: Have you set password tor Firefox stored passwords?

Comment: no i have not set a password and it is a fresh install on my pc

Comment: Post a screenshot of the password prompt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i open firefox it asks me for password to pivII which is luks partion im pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

Good news! This exact issue has been addressed on the [fedoraproject.org forums!](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fix-please-enter-the-password-for-the-pkcs-11-token-piv-ii-rpm/37818)

Comment: the rpm-ostree command doesnt run

Comment: My apologies, but all of my experience is with Debian-based systems. Maybe you could ask for help on the fedora forum?